# jsoup - how to select all links which are in paragraph after a specific h3 (which also has an id and a span class)

Tags: java, jsoup, wiki

I am trying to get all links (more precise the text of the links) from http://virt10.itu.chalmers.se/index.php/Guard as long as they are under the heading "Relations", "Can Instantiate".

```
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Relations">Relations</span></h2>
<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Can_Instantiate">Can Instantiate</span></h3>
<p><a href="/index.php/Attention_Demanding_Gameplay" title="Attention Demanding Gameplay">Attention Demanding Gameplay</a>, 
<a href="/index.php?title=Conflicts&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Conflicts (page does not exist)">Conflicts</a>, 
<a href="/index.php/Continuous_Goals" title="Continuous Goals">Continuous Goals</a>, 
<a href="/index.php?title=Ownership&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Ownership (page does not exist)">Ownership</a>, 
<a href="/index.php/Preventing_Goals" title="Preventing Goals">Preventing Goals</a>, 
<a href="/index.php/Reconnaissance" title="Reconnaissance">Reconnaissance</a>, 
<a href="/index.php/Stimulated_Planning" title="Stimulated Planning">Stimulated Planning</a>, 
<a href="/index.php/Trade-Offs" title="Trade-Offs">Trade-Offs</a>
</p>
```

Unfortunately I kind of not understand jsoup (or java). So far I have tried stuff like

```
Elements contentinstantiate = doc.select("span.mw-headline, h3 ~ a");

for (int i=0; i < contentinstantiate.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(contentinstantiate.get(i).text());
}
```

or

```
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");

for (Element link : links) {
    String linkHref = link.attr("title");
    System.out.println(linkHref);
    String linkText = link.text();
    System.out.println(linkText);
}
```

But both don't work and I am at kind of a loss here. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you select h3 and h3 don't have any a tag. i think you must selected p tag

Comment: But if I select p tag how do I make sure that only p is selected under the Heading "Relations"?

Comment: select the parent of p (I think this is easy to do) then select the first child <p> and there you will be tagged

Comment: any idea for the code to get the parent of p in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup next sibling API will help you. You need to select the

```
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Relations">Relations</span></h2>
```

Then you need to iterate to the next element which will be h3.

```
<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Can_Instantiate">Can Instantiate</span></h3>
```

Then you will go to next sibling and you will check for paragraph node

Once your paragraph node is selected extracting links would be easy

For example `H2` next sibling node is `H3` and `H3` next sibling node is `<p>`

Every Jsoup node has below method

```
public Node nextSibling​()
```

Which will iterate it to next sibling

You can read it at [Jsoup doc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#siblingNodes--)

Comment: So my selector would be "Elements contentinstantiate = doc.select("span.mw-headline#Relations, h2");" but to get the next sibling I have to use nextElementsibling() or?

Comment: This will give you an array of elements of H2. Now for each element you can call nextsibling which will give you H3 element. Than again next sibling will give you <p> tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) Is there no possibility of only getting the span class mw-headline with the id "Can_Instantiate"? My "#Relations" doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Yes you can do that. Get the element by Id for "Can_Instantiate". Get the parent of it by using .parent() method and then select the nextElementSibling() which will give you the <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this it's work for me
code :

```
final String url = "http://virt10.itu.chalmers.se/index.php/Guard";
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
         Element contentinstantiate = doc.getElementById("Can_Instantiate").parent().nextElementSibling();
         for(Element e : contentinstantiate.getAllElements()){
             System.out.println(e.text());
         }
```

output :

```
Attention Demanding Gameplay, Conflicts, Continuous Goals, Ownership, Preventing Goals, Reconnaissance, Stimulated Planning, Trade-Offs
Attention Demanding Gameplay
Conflicts
Continuous Goals
Ownership
Preventing Goals
Reconnaissance
Stimulated Planning
Trade-Offs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class StackOverflow50897294 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://virt10.itu.chalmers.se/index.php/Guard").get();
        Elements links = doc.selectFirst("h3 > span[id=\"Can_Instantiate\"]").parent().nextElementSibling().select("a");
        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println(link.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS Selector:

```
#mw-content-text > p:nth-child(18) > a
```

Here is the code snippet to get the text of the titles.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://virt10.itu.chalmers.se/index.php/Guard").get();
            List<String> titles = doc.select("#mw-content-text > p:nth-child(18) > a").eachText();

            for (String title : titles) {
                System.out.println(title);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Click [here](http://try.jsoup.org/~J8j2EGo1Z3xtjgceEwMrxv3GdDI) for a quick review.